# Rails nested form with has_many :through, how to edit attributes of join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, nested, nested-forms

How do you edit the attributes of a join model when using accepts_nested_attributes_for?

I have 3 models: Topics and Articles joined by Linkers

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :linkers
  has_many :articles, :through => :linkers, :foreign_key => :article_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles
end
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :linkers
  has_many :topics, :through => :linkers, :foreign_key => :topic_id
end
class Linker < ActiveRecord::Base
  #this is the join model, has extra attributes like "relevance"
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :article
end
```

So when I build the article in the "new" action of the topics controller...

```
@topic.articles.build
```

...and make the nested form in topics/new.html.erb...

```
<% form_for(@topic) do |topic_form| %>
  ...fields...
  <% topic_form.fields_for :articles do |article_form| %>
    ...fields...
```

...Rails automatically creates the linker, which is great.
***Now for my question:*** My Linker model also has attributes that I want to be able to change via the "new topic" form. But the linker that Rails automatically creates has nil values for all its attributes except topic_id and article_id. How can I put fields for those other linker attributes into the "new topic" form so they don't come out nil?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing you are, only in a new/create action... I'm wondering if you could share your controller actions. I want to create a `User` through an `Account` using a `Relationship` as a `linker`... but I can't figure out what the new and create actions are meant to look like... would you mind?

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Figured out the answer. The trick was:

```
@topic.linkers.build.build_article
```

That builds the linkers, then builds the article for each linker. So, in the models:
topic.rb needs `accepts_nested_attributes_for :linkers`
linker.rb needs `accepts_nested_attributes_for :article`

Then in the form:

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |topic_form| %>
  ...fields...
  <%= topic_form.fields_for :linkers do |linker_form| %>
    ...linker fields...
    <%= linker_form.fields_for :article do |article_form| %>
      ...article fields...
```

Comment: Rails 3 update: the form_for and field_for need <%= %> instead of <% %> if you're using Rails 3.

Comment: I would add code backticks around the two accepts_nested_attributes_for lines you added.  I missed that info repeatedly while just scanning the code -- once I read it thoroughly, I caught that missed detail and it solved my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: honestly, this is the kind of full example that the rubyonrails.org guides need.

Comment: Visual clarity really does go a long way, T.J. Schuck.

Comment: @Arcolye what are your strong parameters? I'm stuck in a similar problem. Can you help me?

Answer (score 7):

When the form generated by Rails is submitted to the Rails `controller#action`, the `params` will have a structure similar to this (some made up attributes added):

```
params = {
  "topic" => {
    "name"                => "Ruby on Rails' Nested Attributes",
    "linkers_attributes"  => {
      "0" => {
        "is_active"           => false,
        "article_attributes"  => {
          "title"       => "Deeply Nested Attributes",
          "description" => "How Ruby on Rails implements nested attributes."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how `linkers_attributes` is actually a zero-indexed `Hash` with `String` keys, and not an `Array`? Well, this is because the form field keys that are sent to the server look like this:

```
topic[name]
topic[linkers_attributes][0][is_active]
topic[linkers_attributes][0][article_attributes][title]
```

Creating the record is now as simple as:

```
TopicController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @topic = Topic.create!(params[:topic])
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that has been assumed all along with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: @Arcolye - Finding this information on the internet for an association like this was such a pain at the time -- maybe my google-fu was off that day. I wanted to at least document it here as I as my co-worker and I just assumed rails converted linked_attributes to an array, instead of a zero indexed hash. Hopefully this tidbit helps someone in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

A quick GOTCHA for when using has_one in your solution.
I will just copy paste the answer given by user [KandadaBoggu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163203/kandadaboggu) in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472982/using-build-with-a-has-one-association-in-rails).

---

The `build` method signature is different for  `has_one` and `has_many` associations.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :messages
end
```

The build syntax for `has_many` association:

```
user.messages.build
```

The build syntax for `has_one` association:

```
user.build_profile  # this will work

user.profile.build  # this will throw error
```

Read the `has_one` association [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001834) for more details.