# Nested :has_many, :through attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I am using a has_many :through to create an association between two models using a pass-through called  `list_items` :

user.rb:

```
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :wishes, :through => :list_items
```

wishe.rb:

```
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :users, :through => :list_items
```

list_item.rb:

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wish
```

This is working great, however,  `list_items`  has additional attributes for the model  `wishes`  that I'd like to access based on criteria from  `users`  ( `current_user`  to be exact). I can currently access this attribute using code like this:

wishes_controller.rb:

```
  @wishes = current_user.wishes
```

index.html.haml:

```
 -wish.list_items.each do |list_item|
    -if list_item.user_id == current_user.id
        =list_item.list_position
```

Which works fine, however, I'm betting there's a more elegant way to do this, being able to access it like  `wishes.list_position` (which would pull the appropriate list_position based on the current_user id). I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212622/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through-options) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408872/rails-has-many-through-find-by-extra-attributes-in-join-model) (and a number of additional places) but I have not been able to translate these concepts to my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Need data from rails join table, has_many :through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874702/need-data-from-rails-join-table-has-many-through/8874831)

Try this.
user.rb:

`has_many :wishes, :through => :list_items, :select => 'wishes.*, list_items.list_position as list_position'`

This gives you:

```
- @wishes.each do |wish|
  = wish.list_position
```

Comment: worked perfect! so this code selects the list_position (list_items.list_position) and creates 'list_position' (as list_position) for each wish?

Comment: Yeah, you can call it whatever you want, but unless you have a `list_position` attribute on your wish object as well, that should do the trick