# Merge two forms rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Basiclly i have the same issue like @user1224344 here:

[How to submit multiple, duplicate forms from same page in Rails - preferably with one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395970/how-to-submit-multiple-duplicate-forms-from-same-page-in-rails-preferably-wit)

And the first answer looks quite nice, but i as rails beginner have problems to transpose it in my project. Ok i have two forms with the same controller that should be saved with only one submit button:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<%= form_for([@patient, @patient.treatments.build]) do |f| %>
<th><%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :typ %></th>
<th><%= f.text_field :content %></th>
<th><%= f.hidden_field :note, :id => "canvascontent" %></th>
<th><%= f.text_field :day, :value => Date.today %></th>
<th><%= f.submit  :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary', :onclick => "sketch.toDataURL()"  %></th>
<th><input type="button" onclick="sketch.clearRecording()" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" value="Löschen"></th>
<% end %>
</tr>
</table>


<table width="100%">
<tr>
<%= form_for([@patient, @patient.treatments.build]) do |f| %>
<th><%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :typ %></th>
<th><%= f.text_field :content , :id => "inputbox"%></th>
<th><%= f.text_field :day, :value => Date.today %></th>
<th><%= f.submit  :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary'%></th>
<% end %>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for help! Espacially on sunday night(at least here in germany)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're fairly close.

The trick is that both forms should be **nested** within the form that submits them, which should be another model. I don't know how your app is put together, but I'll assume that Patients *have many* Treatments. Your models should include this:

**patient.rb**

```
attr_accessible :treatments_attributes, etc...
has_many :treatments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatments
```

**treatment.rb**

```
belongs_to :patient
```

As you can see, **patient** accepts the attributes for its **treatments** (thus the third and first line in that model). So you actually need to wrap the treatment forms in a patient form, so that you're submitting the patient form with *its nested treatments*. Something like this:

```
<%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for @patient.build_treatment do |tf| %>
    <%= render 'treatment_form', locals: { form: tf } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for @patient.build_treatment do |tf| %>
    <%= render 'treatment_form', locals: { form: tf } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

So you've got that one form for the **patient** that's submitting both treatment forms, automatically associated with the patient. I may have messed up some of the specifics there, but that's the basic idea.

**EDIT** -- you may want to check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212622/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through-options). It's best to put the building of the treatment form objects in your controller like they do in that question. And you may want to check out the [Rails API for more specific help on accepts_nested_attributes_for.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Also, in case it's unclear, the "locals" thing is just passing the treatment form object to a partial under the variable name "form", so in that partial, you'd write <%= form.label :whatever %>... etc, within that partial.

If you build out the form objects in your controller --

```
@patient.build_treatments #may not be exactly this, but it's close
```

-- then you can do this in your view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :treatment do |tf| %>
```

**Also, if it's not clear**, your partial would look something like this, based on your above code:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th><%= form.collection_select :category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :typ %></th>
    <th><%= form.text_field :content , :id => "inputbox"%></th>
    <th><%= form.text_field :day, :value => Date.today %></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Other layout that might be more intuitive:**

**main view**

```
<%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
  <%= render 'treatment_form', form: f %>
<% end %>
```

**partial view**

```
<%= form.fields_for :treatment do |field| %>
  <% field.label :whatever %> #...
```

In other words, you'd move the call to fields_for inside the partial, which might make more sense. Shouldn't actually change how anything really works.

Comment: Man that looks so good! You really helped me! And incidentally you have an very cool profile pic! But i have an little problem, in the partial _treatment_form i get the error: undefined local variable or method `form' for

Comment: Huh. That should work. That's what we're doing with "locals". Basically "locals" is a hash of variables local to the partial. You're saying "form" will be a variable equal to "tf" in that partial. At any rate, you should also be able to do <%= render 'treatment_form', form: tf %> Let me know if that works.

Comment: Ok now it worked with form: tf! I will test it and then i rate your answer! Thanks again! Are you professional Rails developer?

Comment: Ha. Recently started, yeah. Glad that helped. I learned rails/coding not too long ago, and I remember it all being super confusing, so hopefully that cleared this up a bit.

Comment: Ok your answer was in any case correct, and very good! But so far it wont really work, because something in the patient controller is not defined but i moved that to another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776091/unknownattributeerror-in-controller