# UnknownAttributeError in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

With the help of @Sasha i created an nested form for treatments in patients:

Now i get this error:

```
UnknownAttributeError in PatientsController#update

unknown attribute: treatment
```

My patients update controller actually looks like this:

```
def update
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @patient.update_attributes(params[:patient])
      format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And the form like this:

```
<%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for ([@patient, @patient.treatments.build]) do |tf| %>
    <%= render 'treatment_form', form: tf  %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for ([@patient, @patient.treatments.build]) do |tf| %>
    <%= render 'treatment_form', form: tf  %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

So i have no clue what i have to add to my patients controller?

I changed my code like @JimLim recomended, but i get the same error:

```
 ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PatientsController#update

 unknown attribute: treatment

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"put",
"authenticity_token"=>"OPuS9Mmk3guiV20nkw5OaPUFyjVow49H+MMxY37O0r0=",
 "patient"=>{"treatment"=>{"category_id"=>"9",
 "content"=>"dsfsdf",
"day"=>"2013-07-21"}},
"commit"=>"Update Patient",
 "id"=>"9"}
```

Comment: What does your Patient model look like?

Comment: attr_accessible :alter, :nachnahme, :ort, :strasse, :telefon, :vorname, :treatment_attributes, :treatment
  has_many :treatments
  has_many :categories, :through => :treatments
  has_many :paintings, :through => :treatments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatments

Comment: Hey again. "treatment" shouldn't be in attr_accessible. It's not an attribute of patient; it's another model entirely. You have treatment_attributes (which may need to be changed to treatments_attributes, not sure), because you're saying you accept the *attributes* for treatment, but treatment itself is not part of the patient model. If you remove that, it may fix things. At any rate, it should probably be removed.

Comment: Will you please include the contents of the POST request from the Rails log?

Comment: Have you fixed this? If not, I'd remove :treatment from the attr_accessible list in patient.rb. It shouldn't be there. Only :treatments_attributes should. I think that might at least contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters include a `treatment` key that is not an attribute in your Patient model. If that is the case, you need to

1. change the form such that the key is `treatments` instead of `treatment`, and
2. add [#accepts_nested_attribute_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) in your Patient model.

For example,

```
<%= f.fields_for :treatments, @patient.treatments.build do |tf| %>
  <%= render 'treatment_form', form: tf  %>
<% end %>

class Patient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatments
end
```

A more detailed explanation is available in the [documentation for fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Comment: Thanks. My guess was right, and the answer still applies. Please accept my answer if it worked for you.