# Rails: Trying to save two new models with one as a FK to the other from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok, there's a chance all I need is sleep, but I've been at this for a while. Here's what I have.

I have an application to create/manage teams. These teams have a captain who can manage the team. When a user creates a new team, they should automatically be created as a captain of the team.

Links that I've referenced that I feel should be more useful than I'm making them:

- [Merge two forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775118/merge-two-forms-rails) (Combining two models in one form)
- [Rails nested form with has_many :through, how to edit attributes of join model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model)
- [Building complex forms](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms)

I feel like the problem I'm running into is that in my situation I need to create both the team and the captain and tie them together. Where as in these links it seems like the team would already be created and the captain would be tied to it in a separate form.

Relevant code

Models:

team.rb

```
has_many :captain
accepts_nested_attributes_for :captain
```

captain.rb

```
belongs_to :team
```

Team Form:

```
<%= form_for(@team) do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for @team.captain do |tf| %>
        <%= render 'captain/form', locals: { form: tf } %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true  %>

    <%= f.label :team_color%>
    <%= f.text_field :team_color, :required => true %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Captain Form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :auto_search %>
    <%= f.check_box :auto_search %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :sub_list_first %>
    <%= f.check_box :sub_list_first %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :degrees_of_separation %>
    <%= f.number_field :degrees_of_separation %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :search_timer %>
    <%= f.number_field :search_timer, value: 0 %>
</p>
```

teams_controller.rb

```
def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @team.save
            # These lines added during edit
            @team.captain_users.build
            @team.captain_users.first.save

            format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @team.id }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

def team_params
    # I think I need captain_attributes here also?
    params.require(:team).permit(:name, :team_color)
end
```

This then shows the Captain fields in the same form as the team fields. But from here clicking submit does nothing. I'm not even positive if what I'm asking is possible. Right now (disregarding maybe some ajax/remote call), I'm thinking about just creating a team and then a captain and adding some notification or redirecting to captain settings.

EDIT: I seem to have it working now. I followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) guide. I'm still not positive what was happening, but I'm glad it's cleared up now.

Comment: "But from here clicking submit does nothing." And what happens when you reload the web page (browser refresh) and then fill out the form and click submit?

Comment: Still nothing. Still very early in the project so I've dropped the db and remigrated. Tried incognito, logging in with a different user. Clicking that submit button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be quite reasonable to call the ***relation*** between `team` and `captain` as

`team ---> has_one :captain` instead of `has_many`

```
#team.rb

has_one :captain
accepts_nested_attributes_for :captain
```

Then in your `new` method add this line `@team.build_captain` and in your form, change this line `<%= f.fields_for @team.captain_user do |tf| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :captain do |tf| %>`

***Update:***

Include `captain_attributes` in `team_params`

```
def team_params
  params.require(:team).permit(:name, :team_color, captain_attributes: [:id, :auto_search, :sub_list_first, degrees_of_separation, :search_timer])
end
```

Comment: I've made those changes, and it's loading the nested form fine, but still not reacting when the submit button is pressed

Comment: @ELepolt Can you include form code for captain fields also please?

Comment: So close. It's accepting everything on the submit, but it seems that I can't create a captain still. What do I need on the create method to extract the captain parameters to create that new model? Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: @ELepolt Can you include the server log with params generated?

Comment: Also, I did leave the has_many captains on team.rb because I want a team to be able to have multiple captains later. Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EzPPRuQYLASRqVuuWieeIrtOfEE4VcwRbn8C+jr32FA4GwpM1foPMP5Yzwx2Uu9DY44nNygvCzQUO6ikL/qV6g==", "team"=>{"captain_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "auto_search"=>"0", "sub_list_first"=>"0", "degrees_of_separation"=>"", "search_timer"=>"0"}}, "competition_level"=>"", "coed"=>"0", "minimum_age"=>"", "name"=>"", "team_color"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Team"}

Comment: So I see now that I can use @team.captain.first and get all the info inside of those parameters. Is there a best way to save that to a new captain?

Comment: <3 Totally forgot about that concept.