# Rails Error creating form_for for a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Guys in my system I have Products. And the products have min/max stock for each store.
In app/views/product/edit I'm trying to create a way to update it.
So i'm trying something like that:

```
<%= form_for @product.product_stores, :url => {:action => "update_stocks"} do |form| %>
  <% @product.product_stores.each do |e| %>
    <strong><%= e.store.name %></strong> <br/>
    <%= e.id %> <br/>
        
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <%= form.label :min_stock_days, class: "col-form-label" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <%= form.text_field :min_stock_days, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And I 'm getting the error on the screen:

```
undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 
[#<ProductStore id: 913, min_stock_days: nil, max_stock_days: nil, product_id: 975, store_id: 24, created_at: "2024-01-17 16:14:53.475034000 -0300", updated_at: "2024-01-17 16:14:53.475034000 -0300">, 
#<ProductStore id: 11617, min_stock_days: nil, max_stock_days: nil, product_id: 975, store_id: 1, created_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.503417000 -0300", updated_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.503417000 -0300">, 
#<ProductStore id: 11618, min_stock_days: nil, max_stock_days: nil, product_id: 975, store_id: 2, created_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.506141000 -0300", updated_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.506141000 -0300">, 
#<ProductStore id: 11619, min_stock_days: nil, max_stock_days: nil, product_id: 975, store_id: 3, created_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.508833000 -0300", updated_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.508833000 -0300">, 
#<ProductStore id: 11620, min_stock_days: nil, max_stock_days: nil, product_id: 975, store_id: 4, created_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.511535000 -0300", updated_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.511535000 -0300">, 
#<ProductStore id: 11621, min_stock_days: nil, max_stock_days: nil, product_id: 975, store_id: 5, created_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.514277000 -0300", updated_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.514277000 -0300">, 
#<ProductStore id: 11622, min_stock_days: nil, max_stock_days: nil, product_id: 975, store_id: 6, created_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.516974000 -0300", updated_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.516974000 -0300">, 
#<ProductStore id: 11623, min_stock_days: nil, max_stock_days: nil, product_id: 975, store_id: 7, created_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.519660000 -0300", updated_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.519660000 -0300">, 
#<ProductStore id: 11624, min_stock_days: nil, max_stock_days: nil, product_id: 975, store_id: 23, created_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.522390000 -0300", updated_at: "2024-01-17 16:58:08.522390000 -0300">]>
Did you mean?  to_set
               to_ary
```

How can I fix it?
What is the correct way to implement that?

---

I solved it in parts, thanks for @Arup Rakshit.

My Solution was:
in models/product.rb I add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_stores, update_only: true
```

in products_controller.rb I add in product_params

```
product_stores: [:min_stock_days, :max_stock_days]
```

and in the view a change to:

```
<%= form_for @product, as: :post, method: :post, :url => {:action => "update_stocks"} do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :product_stores, @product.product_stores.each do |ps|%>
    <strong> <%= ps %> </strong>
      <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <%= ps.label :min_stock_days, class: "col-form-label" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <%= ps.text_field :min_stock_days, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
        <%= ps.label :max_stock_days, class: "col-form-label" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <%= ps.text_field :max_stock_days, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit "Salvar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

Now, I still having a problem that is...
I dont know each min/max field is for whats store?
Because I dont know the name of store that i'm seting.

Comment: You want to update a Product store? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212622/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through-options

Comment: yes, I would like to update the product's min/max stock for all stores in on view.

Comment: check the link above and read also https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @ArupRakshit do you to how to solve this?
Now, I still having a problem that is... I dont know each min/max field is for whats store? Because I dont know the name of store that i'm seting.

Comment: it seems you have solved it. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

My Solution was: in models/product.rb I add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_stores, update_only: true
```

in products_controller.rb I add in product_params

```
product_stores: [:min_stock_days, :max_stock_days]
```

and in the view a change to:

```
<%= form_for @product, as: :post, method: :post, :url => {:action => "update_stocks"} do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :product_stores, @product.product_stores.each do |ps|%>
    <strong> <%= ps.object.store.name %> </strong>
      <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <%= ps.label :min_stock_days, class: "col-form-label" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <%= ps.text_field :min_stock_days, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
        <%= ps.label :max_stock_days, class: "col-form-label" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <%= ps.text_field :max_stock_days, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit "Salvar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

special note here:  `<strong> <%= ps.object.store.name %> </strong>`

When create a `form_for` or when you use `fields_for` in a form it creates a `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` that is a class that extends the Object we are using, so. in my case `ps` is an `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` extending my class ProductStore. So to know witch store i'm filing the data min/max stock I do that `ps.object` (now it is my object) so I complete using `.store.name`

Answer (score 1):

The `form_for` helper method is designed to build a form for a single model instance, not for a collection.

The given implementation attempts to use form_for with a collection of ActiveRecord objects (@product.product_stores), yet form_for expects a single ActiveRecord object.

Fixing that implies creating individual forms for each item in the @product.product_stores collection.

For example by looping through each ProductStore and creating a separate form for each one.

```
<% @product.product_stores.each do |product_store| %>
  <%= form_for product_store, url: {action: "update_stocks"} do |form| %>
    <strong><%= product_store.store.name %></strong> <br/>
    <%= product_store.id %> <br/>
        
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <%= form.label :min_stock_days, class: "col-form-label" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <%= form.text_field :min_stock_days, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This will solve the problem, but will still make the process very slow, having to save stocks store by store.

Comment: consider marking the question as answered if the root issue is solved, that helps other users knowing that there's a suggested fix

Comment: its not completely solved. I still having the problem about not knowing wich store i'm seting the value.