# Rails: Using build with a has_one association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-one, database-relations

In this example, I create a `user` with no `profile`, then later on create a `profile` for that user. I tried using build with a `has_one` association but that blew up. The only way I see this working is using `has_many`. The `user` is supposed to only have at most one `profile`.

I have been trying this. I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But when I do:

```
user.build_profile
```

I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'profiles.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `profiles` WHERE (`profiles`.user_id = 4)  LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way in rails to have 0 or 1 association?

Comment: what exactly did you try? could you, please, post some code?

Answer (score 389, accepted):

The `build` method signature is different for  `has_one` and `has_many` associations.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :messages
end
```

The build syntax for `has_many` association:

```
user.messages.build
```

The build syntax for `has_one` association:

```
user.build_profile  # this will work

user.profile.build  # this will throw error
```

Read the `has_one` association [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001834) for more details.

Comment: The different syntax for the has_one always catches me out... dammit!

Comment: It's funny how the top rated and accepted answer here is answering a different question from the one the OP asked.

Comment: Supposedly if user belonged to profile(meaning user table has foreign_key profile_id in its table) then also building profile for user will work as mentioned above i.e but for new  action only `user.build_profile ` for edit `user.build_profile  if user.profile.nil? ` and  if you want to build profile while creating user then write `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile` this in User model. and in form which user is being created write `<%= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |p| %>` this and go on.

Comment: but why this different behavior was kept for has_one or has_many? There would be some reason while designing, I think and expect.

Comment: @Ajedi32 the answer matches the question's title but not the body.  Given that this (`build_<association>`) is a quite weird and unexpected behaviour in Rails, there's a lot more people looking for this answer than the actual questions' answer, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 19):

Take a good look at the error message. It is telling you that you do not have required column `user_id` in the **profile table**. 
Setting the relationships in the model is only part of the answer.

You also need to create a migration that adds the `user_id` column to the profile table. 
Rails expects this to be there and if it is not you cannot access the profile.

For more information please take a look at this link:

[Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I just figured out my problem. The book I am learning from didn't explain the foreign key creation very well. I created a new migration which adds a foreign key to my model. thanks.

Comment: Do you need to create the column yourself every time? I had this idea that it happened automagically. I don't know where I got that idea.

Comment: You can add the column when generate a model using command line, something like `rails g model profile user:references:index address:string bio:text`.

Answer (score -14):

It should be a `has_one`. If `build` isn't working, you can just use `new`:

```
ModelName.new( :owner => @owner )
```

is the same as

```
@owner.model_names.build
```

Comment: This isn't the same:  if you create a new model_name with build, when @owner is saved then the new model_name will be saved too.  So, you can use build to make a parent and children which will get saved together.  This isn't the case if you make a model_name with .new