# Rails: create on has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi (huge Rails newbie here), I have the following models:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, :user_id, :message => "is already being used"
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shop, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

When I'm about to create a new shop, I get the following error:

```
private method `create' called for nil:NilClass
```

This is my controller:

```
@user = current_user
@shop = @user.shop.create(params[:shop])
```

I've tried different variations by reading guides and tutorials here and there, but I'm more confused than before and can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edited question title to reflect question. Duplicate of [Using build with a has_one association in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472982/using-build-with-a-has-one-association-in-rails)

Comment: you can also use `@user.build_shop(params) `

Answer (score 134, accepted):

First of all, here is how to do what you want:

```
@user = current_user
@shop = Shop.create(params[:shop])
@user.shop = @shop
```

Now here's why your version did not work:

You probably thought that this might work because if User had a `has_many` relation to Shop, `@user.shops.create(params[:shop])` *would* work. However there is a big difference between `has_many` relations and `has_one` relations:

With a `has_many` relation, `shops` returns an ActiveRecord collection object, which has methods that you can use to add and remove shops to/from a user. One of those methods is `create`, which creates a new shop and adds it to the user.

With a `has_one` relation, you don't get back such a collection object, but simply the Shop object that belongs to the user - or nil if the user doesn't have a shop yet. Since neither Shop objects nor nil have a `create` method, you can't use `create` this way with `has_one` relations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sepp2k. I see now why my code couldn't work.

Comment: You could also use `@user.create_shop(params[:shop])`. See [methods added by has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has_one).

Comment: The answer chosen works, but @nates solution works also.  +1 to both of you.

Comment: +1 to the answer because I was wondering the same, +1 to the answer for explaining why this is and +1 to the comment for giving the best solution.

Comment: The distinction between the return values (the collection with `has_many` vs the object or nil from `has_one`) was a super helpful distinction. Thank you!

Answer (score 252):

A more concise way to do this is with:

```
@user.create_shop(params[:shop])
```

See [methods added by has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one) in the Ruby on Rails guides.

Comment: This is definitely more better approach

Comment: Beware that if you create_shop more than once that it will delete the previous shop.  For instance if you run `@user.create_shop(params[:shop_one_info])` it will create shop_one, BUT if you run `@user.create_shop(params[:shop_two_info])` that it will delete the first shop and create the second one.

Comment: The above comment about deleting the previous shop is for Rails 3.2.18, don't know about more recent versions.  Can't edit comment after 5 min -_-

Comment: Found a solution, I did not set uniqueness on the associated model, so make sure you do as how it is set up in this example's Shop model.

Comment: you can alse use `@user.build_shop(params)`

Answer (score 8):

Two more ways if you want `save` instead of `create`:

```
shop = @user.build_shop
shop.save

shop = Show.new
shop.user = @user
shop.save
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to above answers -

```
@user.create_shop(params[:shop])
```

Above syntax creates new record but it subsequently deletes similar existing record.

Alternatively, if you do not want to trigger delete callback

```
Shop.create(user_id: user.id, title: 'Some unique title')
```

This [thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20514) might be helpful. [Click here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20514)