# How to seed the path to an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

`Organization` and `Image` have a `1-to-1 relationship`. `Image` has a column called `filename`, which stores the path to a file. I have such a file included in the asset pipeling: `app/assets/other/image.jpg`. How can I include the path to this file when seeding?

I have tried in my seeds file:

```
@organization = ...
@organization.image.create!(filename: File.open('app/assets/other/image.jpg'))
# I also tried:
# @organization.image.create!(filename: 'app/assets/other/image.jpg')
```

Both generate the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for nil:NilClass
```

I checked with the `debugger` and can confirm that it's *not* `@organization` that is nil.
How can I make this work and add the path to the file to the `Image` model?

---

**Update**: I tried the following:

```
@image = Image.create!(organization_id: @organization.id,
                       filename: 'app/assets/other/image.jpg')
```

And I also tried:

```
image = @organization.build_image(filename: 'app/assets/other/image.jpg')
image.save
```

Upon seeding both attempts produce the error:

```
CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart: You tried to assign a String or a Pathname to an uploader, for security reasons, this is not allowed.
```

Comment: the filename contains a path , so you need to do
`@organization.image.create!(filename: 'app/assets/other/image.jpg')`

Comment: See `# I also tried:` in my post. Isn't that what you mean? If I do that, I get the error upon seeding: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'create!' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: using File.open is different from using the path directly, and i guess the path is what you really need on the filename attribute

Comment: Just to be clear: Using `@organization.image.create!(filename: 'app/assets/other/image.jpg')` instead of `@organization.image.create!(filename: File.open('app/assets/other/image.jpg'))` still generates the error `NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: @organization.image.create not work with 1-to-1 relation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your error is clearly telling what the issue is. It turns out that `@organization` doesn't have any image yet. So try

```
file  = File.open(File.join(Rails.root,'app/assets/other/image.jpg'))
image = @organization.build_image(filename: file)
image.save
```

Comment: Thanks @GB. I tried it but it generated upon seeding the error: `CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart: You tried to assign a String or a Pathname to an uploader, for security reasons, this is not allowed.`.

Comment: for more help you can see https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-%22Upload%22-from-a-local-file

Answer (score 3):

You are defining one to one relationship between Organization and Image, create action will not work, you have two ways to do this

**1.** Change association to one to many to make you code working

**2.** Another one is to do like this:

```
@image = Image.create(#your code)
@image.organization = @organization
```

Follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839779/rails-create-on-has-one-association)

Comment: Thanks! Please see the update I added to the OP, for the error message that option 2 generates for me.