# NoMethodError in VerificationsController#create (has_one relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller, routes

I'm using a `has_one` relationship and am getting an error. The `create` method isn't using `create` to find the params.

Error Log:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `create' for #<Verification:0x007fcb71e2bd98>):
  app/controllers/verifications_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

verificationsController:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @verification = current_user.verification.create(verification_params)
end


private
        def verification_params
            params.require(:verification).permit(:user_id, :paypal_firstname, :paypal_lastname, :paypal_email, :paypal_verified)
        end
```

routes:

```
devise_for :users ,
       :path => '' ,
       :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
       :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks',
                :registrations => 'registrations', :verifications => 'verifications'
              }


 resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do

 end

resources :users do
  resources :verifications, only: [:create]
end

get '/users/:id/paypal_verification' => 'users#paypal_verification'
patch '/users/:id/paypal_verification' => 'users#paypal_verification'
```

usersController:

```
def paypal_verification
    # @verification = @user.verification.new
    @user = current_user
@verification = Verification.create(params[:verification])
@user.verification = @verification
end
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Also, proper/correct grammar and formatting is very important as it helps us answer and others to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `current_user.create_verification(verification_params)`.

More details here: [Rails: create on has_one association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839779/rails-create-on-has-one-association)