# One-to-one polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism

I have two types of 'owner', each of which can have one 'preference'.

This is my current set up (i.e. how I imagine a one-to-one polymorphic would work):

```
Company.rb
  has_one :pref, :as => :owner

Representative.rb
  has_one :pref, :as => :owner

Pref.rb
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
```

I then try the following commands:

```
Company.first.owner => nil
Company.first.owner.build => error
```

How can I get this relationship working?

---

Update: details on the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
from (irb):10
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

My migration:

```
create_table :prefs do |t|
    t.integer :owner_id, :null => true
    t.string :owner_type, :null => true
    ...
end
```

### Last question

```
# after manually building a pref to link to this representative...
Representative.first.pref => finds pref
Representative.last.pref.create => error

NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for "#<Pref:0x00000106a18ce8>":Pref
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `method_missing'
```

This is so confusing!

---

### Answer:

See: [Using build with a has_one association in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472982/using-build-with-a-has-one-association-in-rails)

```
Representative.last.build_pref => works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the error? Did you migrate your database properly? i.e.:

```
t.string :owner_type
t.integer :owner_id
```

Comment: @adrian - Yes, I do have those two fields confirmed in my database schema in the Pref table.

Comment: You're trying to access `owner`, but you have defined your association as `pref`. Try `Company.first.pref`.

Comment: @adrian - still not working... I'm going to try restarting my server, database etc.

Comment: @adrian - I've run into a similar problem. I'm sorry for all the follow-ups, this is very confusing!

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of twisted relationship, but ... I would rather do it this way:

Remeber about :ownerable_type, :ownerable_id fields as well.

```
Company.rb
  has_one  :owner, :as => :ownerable

Representative.rb
  belongs_to :ownerable, :polymorphic => true

Owner.rb
  belongs_to :ownerable, :polymorphic => true
```

After that

```
Company.first.owner, should work
```

as well as

```
Owner.first.ownerable
```

should return the Company

In fact it seems for me better when you have:

```
Company.rb
  belongs_to :ownerable, :polymorphic => true

Representative.rb
  has_many :companies, :polymorphic => true, :as => :ownerable

Owner.rb
  has_many :companies, :polymorphic => true, :as => :ownerable
```

You could switch to has_one of course.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment! I realized after reading your answer that I mistyped the relationship - if you consider the name for my polymorphic relationship as 'ownerable' that's more like what I have.