# ActiveRecord Association select counts for included records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

Example

```
class User  
  has_many :tickets 
end
```

I want to create association which contains logic of count tickets of user and use it in includes (user has_one ticket_count)

```
Users.includes(:tickets_count)
```

I tried

```
  has_one :tickets_count, :select => "COUNT(*) as tickets_count,tickets.user_id " ,:class_name => 'Ticket', :group => "tickets.user_id", :readonly => true  

User.includes(:tickets_count)

 ArgumentError: Unknown key: group
```

In this case association query in include should use count with group by ...
How can I implement this using rails?

**Update**

- I can't change table structure
- I want AR generate 1 query for collection of users with includes

**Update2**

I know SQL an I know how to select this with joins, but my question is now like "How to get data" . My question is about building association which I can use in includes. Thanks

**Update3**
I tried create association created like  user has_one ticket_count , but

1. looks like has_one doesn't support association extensions
2. has_one doesn't support :group option
3. has_one doesn't support finder_sql

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment but would just like to add a link to this post as a great reference for how to implement counter caching as suggested by djtal64 above: https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/19/activerecords-counter-cache.html However if you're using Rails 6 there is a fairly significant gotcha in that the whole object must be passed to the created one when updating it: https://dev.to/loribbaum/rails-5-2-x-rails-6-countercache-gotcha-3bgc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User

  has_one :tickets_count, :class_name => 'Ticket', 
    :select => "user_id, tickets_count",
    :finder_sql =>   '
        SELECT b.user_id, COUNT(*) tickets_count
        FROM   tickets b
        WHERE  b.user_id = #{id}
        GROUP BY b.user_id
     '
end
```

**Edit:**

It looks like the `has_one` association does not support the `finder_sql` option.

You can easily achieve what you want by using a combination of `scope`/`class` methods

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.include_ticket_counts
    joins(
     %{
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT b.user_id, COUNT(*) tickets_count
         FROM   tickets b
         GROUP BY b.user_id
       ) a ON a.user_id = users.id
     }
    ).select("users.*, COALESCE(a.tickets_count, 0) AS tickets_count")
  end    
end
```

Now

```
User.include_ticket_counts.where(:id => [1,2,3]).each do |user|
  p user.tickets_count 
end
```

This solution has performance implications if you have millions of rows in the `tickets` table. You should consider filtering the JOIN result set by providing `WHERE` to the inner query.

Comment: rails 3.2 gives me ArgumentError: Unknown key: sql

Comment: has_one has next options [:class_name, :foreign_key, :select, :conditions, :include, :extend, :readonly, :validate, :remote, :dependent, :counter_cache, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :order, :as, :autosave]

Comment: @Fivell, updated the answer. I was supposed to use `finder_sql` instead of `sql`. I have updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: I tried see my comment , finder_sql is not supported by has_one association. It gives me ArgumentError: Unknown key: finder_sql

Comment: intresting thanks. So you mean this is only one possible way ?
How do you think why such simpe at first sight logic is not supported by associations ?

Comment: The `has_one` has always been a foster child among the associations. Even the API signature is inconsistent ( If you want proof, look at up votes I am gathering for this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472982/using-build-with-a-has-one-association-in-rails/2473317#2473317). IMHO, your case is better served by the 2nd solution I have suggested as it supports condition chaining and probably faster than using association(as the user data and the count is retrieved in one SQL).

Comment: yes, your second solution works at least) as for now it's best answer!

Comment: how do you think if such associations will be supported in future? Is there some kind of roadmap for this somewhere?

Comment: I do not have any idea about the road-map. You might be better off declaring a new table to store all the `stats` for users and adding a `has_one :stat` association. Update the stat row when ever a user stat changes. This will improve stat query performance significantly. I know you you can't alter your current tables, may be you can introduce a new one?

Comment: I have no such task, this question is just my curiosity =)

Comment: Very nice solution to avoid the disgusting hack that is `:counter_cache`. Only change I had to make (I'm using Postgres) is changing `.select("users.*, a.tickets_count")` to `.select("users.*, COALESCE(a.tickets_count, 0) AS tickets_count")`

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use for a particular user:

```
user.tickets.count
```

Or if you want this value automatically cached by Rails.

Declare a counter_cache => true option in the other side of the association

```
class ticket
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end
```

You also need a column in you user table named tickets_count.
With this each time you add a new tickets to a user rails will update this column so when you ftech your user record you can simply accs this column to get the ticket count without additional query.

Comment: If you cannot change table structure, then you just need to add a virtual method that returns the count in your `User` model: `def tickets_count; @tickets_count ||= tickets.count; end` and then you can call it as a normal attribute `@user.tickets_count`

Answer (score 7):

Not pretty, but it works:

```
users = User.joins("LEFT JOIN tickets ON users.id = tickets.user_id").select("users.*, count(tickets.id) as ticket_count").group("users.id")
users.first.ticket_count
```

Comment: Tanks for response...but it doesn't work...what if user has no tickets? and how it  groups ticket counts by user?  Did you try it ? Also I want to use includes

Comment: Yes I tried it and it works fine for me. Why do you want to use includes?

Comment: 1) joins uses inner join, left join needed
2) where is group by user.id statement in our example?(needed for count)

Comment: yes of course now it's working... but it's not an answer for my question .. I'm looking a way to build association which I can use in includes method

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't understand your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a method in the User model that does the query?

You wouldn't be modifying the table structure, or you can't modify that either?

Comment: how  I can call this method dynamicly with "includes" ?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a `subselect` scope to `ApplicationRecord`:

```rb
scope :subselect,
  lambda { |aggregate_fn, as:, from:|
    query = self.klass
      .select(aggregate_fn)
      .from("#{self.table_name} _#{self.table_name}")
      .where("_#{self.table_name}.id = #{self.table_name}.id")
      .joins(from)

    select("(#{query.to_sql}) AS #{as}")
  }
```

Then, one might use the following query:

```rb
users = User.select('users.*').subselect('COUNT(*)', as: :tickets_count, from: :tickets)

users.first.ticket_count
# => 5
```