# Rails avoiding N+1 Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

A `post` has `likers` and `comments` children. I want to sort posts based on them.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  scope :latest, -> {
    all.sort_by(&:ranking)
  }

  def ranking
    likers.count + comments.count
  end
end
```

This calls queries like below:

```
  Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 52]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_post_likes" ON "users"."id" = "user_post_likes"."user_id" WHERE "user_post_likes"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 52]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 53]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_post_likes" ON "users"."id" = "user_post_likes"."user_id" WHERE "user_post_likes"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 53]]
```

So I try the following instead:

```
Post.includes(:comments, :likers).all.sort_by(&:ranking)
```

This calls queries like below:

```
  Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" IN (52, 53, 54, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71)
  UserPostLike Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "user_post_likes".* FROM "user_post_likes" WHERE "user_post_likes"."post_id" IN (52, 53, 54, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 46
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 52]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_post_likes" ON "users"."id" = "user_post_likes"."user_id" WHERE "user_post_likes"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 52]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 53]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_post_likes" ON "users"."id" = "user_post_likes"."user_id" WHERE "user_post_likes"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 53]]
```

Why is this happening, and how can I solve it?

**UPDATE:**

I figured out how to solve it, but an answer with a very nice explanation will be nice:

I had to replace `count` with `size`.

**Initial:**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  scope :latest, -> { 
    all.sort_by(&:ranking)
  }

  def ranking
    likers.count + comments.count
  end
end
```

**After:**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def ranking
    likers.size + comments.size
  end
end
```

Then, `N+1 Query` is gone. I got the hint from the fact that when you use `counter_cache`, the same thing happens. In this case, I didn't use `counter_cache` but I still had to use `size` instead of `count`. I assume calling `count` forces Rails to call `COUNT` SQL query and calling `size` makes it use the loaded records in memory.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9209705/4758119

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eager_load` like that:

```
Post.eager_load(:comments, :likers).sort_by(&:ranking)
```

eager loading loads all association in a single query using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

[Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

[3 ways to do eager loading (preloading) in Rails 3 & 4](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/)

Comment: The issue here is not the eager loading, as you can see from the query his associations are loaded up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: The eager_load perform only 1 query and load all data(assosation records) in the memory.

Comment: @MaximusS Nice catch, I forgot about the difference between count and size, size it for ruby enumerables.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is two folds:

First, `sort_by` immediately raises a flag for me:
http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sort%21

It is an `Array` method, meaning you are no longer building an ActiveRecord query, you're doing array transformations.

Since you're including `comments` and `likers` the queries aren't as bad as they could be, but here is the other issue.

The way `.count` works is that's a prefabricated count query `SELECT * FROM table`.

To get the result you want, you will need to build your own count and sort query.

Take a look at this post and hopefully this will give you a better idea on how to optimize this further:
[Rails 3 ActiveRecord: Order by count on association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696005/rails-3-activerecord-order-by-count-on-association)

Comment: You post an example for mysql, in Postgres you need to aggregate all attributes.

Comment: @Зелёный what do you mean aggregate all attributes? I was eluding to building a query to count and sort the ranking, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

in your case best way is to use `counter_cache` for `likers` and `comments`.
More detail you can read [SHORT ARTICLE](http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/). It's very easy and it'll safe time and memory.

If you use `counter_cache`, you shouldn't make several requests to your DB. and now your method will be:

```
def ranking
  likers_count + comments_count
end
```

on the other hand, if you don't want to add columns to table just use `includes`:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  scope :latest, -> { 
    includes(:likers, :comments).sort_by(&:ranking)
  }

  def ranking 
    likers.count + comments.count
  end
end
```

but in this case you'll calculate `likers` and `comments` each time when method calls