# One-to-one association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

My bussiness logic is as follows: I have a number of users. Each user can be either a requester or a worker.

This is how I implemented it in Rails. I'm using devise for authentication.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :confirmed_at
   has_one :requester           
end
```

Here is the requester model.

```
class Requester < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :rating      
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :tasks
end
```

When I tried to test it with cucumber, I defined a method to create a number of users

```
def create_confirmed_user(name,email,password)
  user = User.new(name: name, email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: password, confirmed_at: DateTime.now)
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save
end
```

And create requester from user

```
def create_requester_from_user(email, rating)
  user = User.find_by_email(email)
  requester = Requester.new(rating: rating)
  requester.user = user
  requester.save
  binding.pry #To debug 
  0
end
```

When I debugged with pry, I found that `requester.user` returned a user but `r = Requester.first` then `r.user` return nil (I checked that `r == requester` return true). That is weird.

Speculating that the problem comes from not preparing the test database, I have run `rake db:test:prepare` to check but `r.user` still return nil.

Another question: with this model, can I call `user.requester` to get the requester belongs to this user ?

One more question is that how to implement this bussiness logic properly ? Is Single Table Inheritance (STI) a good choice ? Since I googled and found that using STI has many bad side-effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem from this post [Using build with a has_one association in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472982/using-build-with-a-has-one-association-in-rails): I modified the model only without creating the migration. I need to run this migration after add `belongs_to` to my Requester model: `rails generate migration add_user_id_to_requester user_id:integer`. It's surprised that many documentations don't mention this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a polymorphic association
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: From my understanding and according to this article http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html, I believe that polymorphic association and STI are different.

Comment: STI will work you fine.
Using a gem like https://github.com/brunofrank/class-table-inheritance

will greatly alleviate STI caveats.

Comment: What I'm afraid is that the gem is nearly one year old. However, the gem only answers one question. There are still two questions (as described above) that I can answer.

Comment: I think the cause that requester.user returns a user and r.user returns nil is that requester is stored in memory when called but r is stored in database.