# nested attributes not displaying form correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes

I have a form from user

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :businesses do |field| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= field.label :address %>
      <%= field.text_field :address %>
    </div>   
    <div class="field">
      <%= field.label :city %>
      <%= field.text_field :city %>
    </div>  
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It does not display my fields, but when i change `businesses` to `business`, then it shows, or if I remove the `f` from `f.fields_for`. But I don't think it properly saves into database.

my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businesses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :businesses
en
```

my business model

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :address, :city
  belongs_to :user
end
```

my bussiness migration

```
class CreateBusinesses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :businesses do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :address
      t.string :city

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does the User have any businesses yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should build a business before it can display a form for it:

```
@user.businesses.build
```

Use that before using `fields_for`

Also check out this great gem for managing nested forms:

https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: So user would need to have a business first before the form is displayed? But what if I want user to input a business?

Comment: i was able to display the fields when I put `<%= f.fields_for :businesses, @user.businesses.build do |field| %>` But now when I save my database, the information doesn't show up in the field? Isn't my values should show up in the fields automatically if I want to edit my information? If I do `<%= @user.businesses %>` it shows my saved file.

Comment: And it just keeps adding new data when I try to insert more information into `address` and `city` field, Its supposed to override the original data?

Comment: I figured it out that I'm supposed to put the `@user.businesses.build` in my `new` action in users_controller

Comment: Yes, thats right.. The `build` method works like `Model.new` but for an association. You can't create a form if the association isn't initialized. After you post the form you don't need to initialize it anymore, so you could use something like `@user.businesses.first || @user.businesses.build` to only build it if it doesn't exist. If you  need more businesses to be added, you need to build again for the new ones. (Let the user select the amount of new businesses needed, and build them). But for a more user-friendly way, check out the plugin I mentioned..

Comment: I get a `undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass` when I add `@user.preferences.build`, why ??

Comment: Found it : in a `has_one` relationship, it is `@user.build_preferences`. Found it thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472982/using-build-with-a-has-one-association-in-rails