# Rails: use build to create a model that doesnt exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Lets say I have a model `topic`, and it has one `moderator`. I want to build a new post for a topic.

In my controller:

```
@topic = Topic.find(:id)
@moderator = @topic.moderator.build # error points to this line
```

Error:

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relation is declared in the model as long as it is a has_many you might have been declared:

```
has_many :posts
```

So you need to call:

```
@post = @topic.posts.build
```

Suppossing you have a has_one relation:

```
has_one :moderator

@moderator = @post.build_moderator
```

Solved here:

[Using build with a has_one association in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472982/using-build-with-a-has-one-association-in-rails)

See also the Rails guide re: associations. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jorge - do you know what the method if it's a "has_one"? Or where this is documented in Rails?

Comment: You've changed the question. I've added the answer to has one.

Comment: Thanks! It's strange because when I try your answer for the has_one, I get the `undefined method "build" for nil:NilClass` error.

Comment: Edited to fix my mistake. The method changes for has_one

Comment: See also the Rails guide re: associations. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html