# Rails when creating record, inserting belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

i have a question about associations in rails. The situation is the following:

Models:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :character_stats
end

class CharacterStats < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :character
end
```

Now i need to create stats when a new character is created.

What i doo is this at the moment, i feel like this is a workaround with rails. Is there a more "raily" way to do this?

```
  after_save :character_init  

  def character_init
    create_stats
  end

  def create_stats
    stats = CharacterStats.new
    stats.character_id = self.id // this bothers me!
    stats.save
  end
```

But i feel there should be something like this:

```
stats.character << self
```

Thank You in advance :)

EDIT:

here is how my model look in real life:

```
def create_stats
    race_stats = Race.find(race_id).race_stats
    class_stats = RaceClass.find(race_class_id).class_stats
    stats = CharacterStats.new
    stats.character_id = self.id
    stats.health = race_stats.health + class_stats.health
    stats.mana = race_stats.mana + class_stats.mana
    stats.intellect = race_stats.intellect + class_stats.intellect
    stats.armor = race_stats.armor + class_stats.armor
    stats.magic_resist = race_stats.magic_resist + class_stats.magic_resist
    stats.attack = race_stats.attack + class_stats.attack
    stats.defence = race_stats.defence + class_stats.defence
    stats.save
    self.character_stats_id = stats.id
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in rails way you can use the build_association method [refer doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). Also the association should be created only when parent object is created so use `after_create` callback

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :character_stats

 after_create :create_stats

 def create_stats
    state = self.build_character_stats({}) # empty hash as you are not passing any attributes   
    state.save
 end

end
```

Also, the model name CharacterStats looks plural and that can violate the naming convention and can cause some issue like resolving association class on run time and so.

Answer (score 2):

first of all if you want to create `CharacterStats` after `Character` is created use `after_create` callback. About your question you can use ActiveRecord methods which looks like `create_character_stats` for creating model and `build_character_stats` for initializing model. So you can change your `create_stats` method to something like this

```
def create_stats
  self.create_character_stats
end
```

or you can change your after callback to this

```
after_create :create_character_stats
```

and then you don't need any method for this, but in this case you don't have ability to pass attributes to model creating.

also this question mentioned here [Using build with a has_one association in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472982/using-build-with-a-has-one-association-in-rails)

Comment: This is quite usefull to know, but i have to pass parameters... i will edit my post for that...