# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Rails4 Controller #create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I submit my form I'm seeing this error.

```
 NoMethodError in SellersController#create 
undefined method `sellers' for #
 match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
 match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
```

It's coming from this line in the `sellers_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @seller = current_user.sellers.build(seller_params)  
end
```

Relevant part of the model:

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

View: 
new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@seller) do |f| %>
...      
<% end %>
```

Rake routes runs without an error.

I'm missing something with how rails assumes the `db/view/model` is for my controller. I've been looking through the documentation but nothing is coming to mind.

routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :sellers
 end
```

create_sellers.rb

```
class CreateSellers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sellers do |t|
      ....
        t.references :user, index:true, foreign_key: true
```

I've already tried

- restarting rails
- closing and reopening the terminal
- rolling back the migration and trying it again (no error on migration)

I've looked at the migration/model/controller view and I am not seeing the problem (so Its probably there and obvious).

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :seller
end
```

Comment: `user.rb` has `has_many sellers`?

Comment: see above, a user has one seller. a seller belongs to a user in the models. Looks like the edit lost it

Comment: Can you show your user model?

Comment: if a _a user has one seller_ then why you call `current_user.sellers` ? would not be `current_user.seller` ?

Comment: @ kalelc I've tried that, but I just get this error then. "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass, @seller = current_user.seller.build(seller_params)  "

Comment: Seller model has `build` method?

Comment: build should be another way of saying new, but google is telling me, build should only be used with a collection. so that might be it, trying it now

Comment: Try in your rails console `User.first.seller.inspect`

Comment: @kalelc thanks. Along with the extra s, it was just the build syntax is different for has_one than has_many. Between your help and the comment below this is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user **has one** seller, then you need to change the way you build the association:

```
@seller = current_user.build_seller(seller_params)
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2473317/2241124) that compares the build syntax for `has_many` and `has_one`.