# Adding more data on saving 'has_many :through' associated records by keeping use of the "RoR magical\automatic way"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I followed [this post](http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/) about handling an "`has_many :through => checkboxes`" in which, in order to create user-group relationship records for membership purposes, is just passed a `group_ids` parameter (that is an array of id values) from check box input fields to the `@user.save` method. Using that code all works good in a "RoR magical\automatic way" (RoR set properly `user_id` values in the related `memberships` database table).

However, on saving, I would like to add some extra information to `Membership` records. That is, (following that post content) when it creates the associated records in the `memberships` database table (which database table has `id`, `user_id` and `group_id` columns) I would like to save an extra description information (which, for example, can be represented by a `description` column in that `memberships` table).

**Is it possible to accomplish that by keeping use of the "RoR magical\automatic way"?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model/2278928#2278928

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use the ActiveRecord Callbacks to achieve this :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: It doesn't work in my case since I need to add others information by accessing instance variable data (example: `@current_user.id` - it is not possible to access that variable in a model file).