# Rails has_many :through nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many-through

I have just jumped into `has_many :through` association. I'm trying to implement the ability to save data for all 3 tables (`Physician`, `Patient` and association table) through a single form.

### My migrations:

```
class CreatePhysicians < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :physicians do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreatePatients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :patients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :appointments do |t|
      t.integer :physician_id
      t.integer :patient_id
      t.date :appointment_date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

#### My models:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :physicians
end
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments
end
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

#### My controller:

```
def new
    @patient = Patient.new
    @patient.physicians.build
    @patient.appointments.build
end
```

#### My view (`new.html.rb`):

```
<% form_for(@patient) do |patient_form| %>
  <%= patient_form.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= patient_form.label :name, "Patient Name" %>
    <%= patient_form.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <%  patient_form.fields_for :physicians do |physician_form| %>
    <p>
      <%= physician_form.label :name, "Physician Name" %>
      <%= physician_form.text_field :name %>
    </p>
 <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= patient_form.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', patients_path %>
```

I'm able to create a new `Patient`, `Physician` and associated record for an `Appointment`, but now I want to have field for `appointment_date` too in form. Where should I place fields for `Appointment`s and what changes are required in my controller? I tried googling and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model), but got stuck in some or other error implementing it.

Comment: Another tip: You could use `t.references :patient` instead of `t.integer :patient_id` to create your column of the appropriate type. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#special-helpers

Answer (score 30):

Ok, this little bugger of a question stumped me for a few hours, so I'm going to post my working solution on here in hopes it shaves some time for peeps. This is for Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0. This also overcame a "symbol to integer conversion" issue I had.

**Models:**

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments
end 
   
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician 
  belongs_to :patient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :physician
end

class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end
```

**Controller:**

```
# patients_controller.rb
def new
  @patient= Patient.new 
  @appointments = @patient.appointments.build
  @physician = @appointments.build_physician 
end

def create
  Patient.new(patient_params)
end


def patient_params
   params.require(:patient).permit(:id, appointments_attributes: [:id, :appointment_time, physician_attributes: [:id ] )
end
```

**View**

```
<% form_for(@patient) do |patient_form| %>
  <%= patient_form.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= patient_form.label :name, "Patient Name" %>
    <%= patient_form.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <% patient_form.fields_for :appointments do |appointment_form| %>
    <p>
      <%= appointment_form.label :appointment_date, "Appointment Date" %>
      <%= appointment_form.date_field :appointment_date %>
    </p>

    <% appointment_form.fields_for :physician do |physician_form| %>
      <p>
        <%= physician_form.label :name, "Physician Name" %>
        <%= physician_form.text_field :name %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= patient_form.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', patients_path %>
```

Comment: Oh thanks for that! This bugger also kept me busy for quite some time.

Comment: Dont you have to strong-param-permit the name attribute of physician, too?

Answer (score 7):

"i got it working. I just changed models as follows" : quoted from Shruti in the comments above

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments
end 

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician 
  belongs_to :patient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :physician
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Your patient class accepts nested attributes for both physicians and appointments. Try adding another `fields_for` method for appointment.

```
<% form_for(@patient) do |patient_form| %>
  <%= patient_form.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= patient_form.label :name, "Patient Name" %>
    <%= patient_form.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <% patient_form.fields_for :physicians do |physician_form| %>
    <p>
      <%= physician_form.label :name, "Physician Name" %>
      <%= physician_form.text_field :name %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <% patient_form.fields_for :appointments do |appointment_form| %>
    <p>
      <%= appointment_form.label :appointment_date, "Appointment Date" %>
      <%= appointment_form.date_field :appointment_date %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= patient_form.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', patients_path %>
```

Comment: thanx @andrew for quick reply. I tried code, it results into 2 records getting inserted into appointments table : In 1st record, patient_id & appointment_date gets saved & in 2nd record, physician_id & patient_id gets saved. Any changes required in controller or model?

Comment: @Shruti I think you should remove `@patient.appointments.build`, and in your create action, just use `@patient.save` to save objects.

Comment: @kien if I do so, appointment_date text_field is not visible on my form :(

Comment: are you want to build a new physician same time when create appointments?

Comment: yes..i want to build New Patient, New Physician & associate new Appointment(alongwith appointment_date) at the same time.

Comment: @Shruti I believe you're creating two separate records because of the two `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. I'm not sure, but do you need both? Because you've also linked Patient and Physician class in the same manner, you may be able to get at appointments by only declare `accepts_nested_attributes_for` once.

Comment: actually I am really v. confused as to when to use accepts_nested_attributes_for I have modified my patient model 7 now it looks like this :  `class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
#  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :physicians
end`

Comment: And controller looks like this : 
`def new
    @patient = Patient.new
    @patient.appointments.build
end`
Parameters : 
  `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"NxtZHoSRSYsrOQhfQk/293qdv7K5WZvbhOFOpMiIzSE=", "patient"=>{"name"=>"abc", "physicians"=>{"name"=>"def"}, "appointments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"appointment_date"=>"2012-10-12"}}}, "commit"=>"Create"}`

This throws an error : 
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Physician(#-627416098) expected, got Array(#67561520)):`

Comment: i got it working. I just changed models as follows :
`class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments
end
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :physician
end`

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar situation, but I keep running into errors. Would it be possible for you to post the final, working code? Perhaps as an answer? I suspect it will help not just me, but other people dealing with the same problem.