# How do I create/remove objects to an association through my Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, associations, simple-form, multi-select

I'm wanting to add/remove records to an association from my main form object `Report`.  I have my multiselect drop-down list showing correctly and passing ids correctly to my update action.  However, I'm receiving the following message.

```
Couldn't find all ReportExposures with 'id': (157504, 148644, 152852) (found 0 results, but was looking for 3)
```

Now I know that those ids are actually my `ncaa_game_id`s I'm wanting to assign to the `ReportExposure` record, but I can't put the ReportExposure `id` because it doesn't really exist yet.  What do I need to tweak on my form to get this to work correctly, or do I need to add some code in my update action to handle these?

**Report.rb**

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :report_exposures
end
```

**ReportExposure.rb**

```
class ReportExposure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ncaa_game
  belongs_to :report
end
```

**ReportsController.rb**

```
def update

  # "report_exposure_ids"=>["157504","148644","152852"] -- these ids are really the ncaa_game_ids I want to create new report_exposure objects with...

  respond_to do |format|
    if @report.update(report_params)
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end

end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<select id="report_report_exposure_ids" name="report[report_exposure_ids][]" class="multiselect-dropdownlist" multiple="multiple">
  <% @exposures.each do |season| %>
    <optgroup label="<%= season.first.season %> Season">
      <% season.includes(:home_team, :away_team).order(game_date: :asc).each do |game| %>
        <option value="<%= game.id %>"><%= game.full_description %></option>
      <% end %>
    </optgroup>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change reports to this:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :report_exposures
  has_many :ncaa_games
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ncaa_games
end
```

And read about doing nested forms here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

There are a lot of examples of people asking questions about nested_forms with a has_many through relationship. Take a look at those for guidance:

[Rails has_many :through nested form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506735/rails-has-many-through-nested-form)

Don't try to manipulate the join object (ReportExposure) unless you are actually dealing with adding metadata to that object. That is what the ORM is for.

Comment: If I were to go this way, I would need to do a HABTM relationship with a join table.  I was trying to do the relationship in the way I described in case I had to add meta data in the future. For instance attaching a grade or comment to the `ReportExposure` record.

Comment: I think you can still have both. You can use the has_many_through relationship, and have your form work the way I suggest. If for some reason you want to expose the join table in the form, you will need to create a new record for each game_id that is selected. Your bug is that you are saying `name="report[report_exposure_ids][]"`, and then using game ID as the id in the option.