# What is the alternative for accepts_nested_attributes_for in the belongs_to model activeadmin resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a memberships resource and it belongs to user and club. I want to access the parent attributes i.e for club and user and I read that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for parent side of a relationship. What should I write in my membership model?

I have searched about it both in stackoverflow and activeadmin docs but I did not get a thorough explanation about solving my problem...

My membership model is:
membership.rb

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
    require 'csv'
    belongs_to :club
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Also what should i write in my membership resource which I have already registered with AA...

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506735/rails-has-many-through-nested-form ?

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the following :-
1) has_many: memberships #in user model
2) has_many: memberships #in club model

This will help you access parent attributes from child model :-
**membership.user, membership.club**

Also, you can mention **accepts_nested_attributes_for: memberships** in user model.
When you write this, you can then build a common form for user and membership and modify both of them simultaneously. To achieve this, you will have to allow membership attributes in users_controller.rb.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work([Similar question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506735/rails-has-many-through-nested-form):

```
class Club < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy 
   has_many :users, :through => :memberships
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership 
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy 
   has_many :clubs, :through => :memberships
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership 
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
    require 'csv'
    belongs_to :club
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :club
end
```