# Storing order in a nested form of a many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4 app, with models `Challenge` and `ChallengeList`. It's a many-to-many relationship, so I also have a join table with model `ChallengeListsChallenge`. I defined this last model because I want my `ChallengeLists` to be ordered lists, and so used it to exploit `acts_as_list`:

```
class ChallengeList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :challenge_lists_challenges, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :challenges, :through => :challenge_lists_challenges
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :challenges
end

class ChallengeListsChallenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'position'
  belongs_to :challenge
  belongs_to :challenge_list
  acts_as_list :scope => :challenge_list
end
```

This works fine.

---

In my HTML, I have a form that allows the user to define a new `ChallengeList`. It has a nested form for `Challenges`:

```
= f.fields_for :challenges do |challenge_builder|
  .field
    = challenge_builder.text_field :description
```

But I would also like the user to be able to change the position. So I thought I'd be smart, add a field for position:

```
    = challenge_builder.text_field :position
```

Of course, this doesn't work, because 'position' is set on join items, not `Challenge` items.

Having a nested form for `ChallengeListsChallenges` would give me access to the position, but is not cool because:

1. I need a reference to my `ChallengeList` id (which is not insurmountable, but not pretty either)
2. I can only reference existing `Challenge` ids

So what can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to change the Challenge and the ChallengeList in the same form? Yea, that's going to get a bit ugly. Maybe you show allow reordering on the show page using a jQuery plugin, and no reordering on the edit page.

Comment: That's what I'm after! I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model?rq=1), which looks to be about the same thing I'm trying to achieve. So I'mma try that out, and report my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model?rq=1):

Set up model dependencies like so:

```
class ChallengeList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :challenge_lists_challenges, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :challenges, :through => :challenge_lists_challenges
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :challenge_lists
end

class ChallengeListsChallenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'position'
  belongs_to :challenge
  belongs_to :challenge_list
  acts_as_list :scope => :challenge_list
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :challenges
end
```

And a doubly nested form like so:

```
= form_for @challenge_list do |f|
  = f.fields_for :challenge_lists_challenges do |links_form|
    .field
      = links_form.number_field :position
      %br/
    = links_form.fields_for :challenge do |challenge_form|
      .field
        = challenge_form.text_field :description
    = challenge_form.text_field :id
```

And it should work.