# Rails 4 Multipleselect

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, multiple-select, multipleselection

I'm trying to create a form using form_for which will add Employees. For an employee i want to assign multiple specializations such as c#, asp, etc as the values dynamically. I'm using the following code in the form

```
<%= f.select :specilization, Specialization.all.collect{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

I've also made HABTM between employees and specialization like

**Employee.rb**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :specializations
end
```

**Specialization.rb**

```
class Specialization < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
end
```

with these done, im not able to save the selected values in db(MySQl). Would appreciate if anyone could solve my problem or guide me on how to get this right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this by using `has_many :through`  and then in my form the select is a `field_for` on the join model. Like this:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees_specializations
  has_many :specializations, through: :employees_specializations
  # we will be creating these join models on the employee form
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees_specializations
end

class Specialization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees_specializations
  has_many :employees, through: :employees_specializations
end

class EmployeesSpecialization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :specializations
end
```

Now it's important to note that with this simplified approach I'm assuming Specializations already exist in the database and we're just selecting them and joining them to the employee we're creating/editing:

```
# in your controller make sure to build at least 1 new instance, the fields_for needs this
@employee.employees_specializations.build

# remember to add to your strong parameters the new join attributes
params.require(:employee).permit(
  # ... other attributes ...
  employees_specializations_attributes: [:id, :specialization_id]
)
```

You need to declare `:id, :specialization_id` as sub fields since `employees_specializations_attributes` will be a nested hash with those keys inside.

```
# now in your form use fields_for
<%= f.fields_for :employees_specializations do |ef| %>
  <%= ef.select :specialization_id, Specialization.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, {}, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

That `f.fields_for :employees_specializations` will create form fields named `employee[employees_specializations_attributes][][specialization_id]`. Which basically says we are creating a nested association `employees_specializations` and setting that nested association's `specialization_id` (remember employees_specialization `belongs_to :specialization`) to the selected specialization. Note the `[]` in the middle of the field name, this means its an array of nested `employees_specializations`.

Post that and barring any validation errors you should be able to create/edit an employee and set it's specializations by selecting from a list of existing specializations and creating a join model between them.

Further reading:

- http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for
- http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for
- http://laptite.github.io/blog/2014/02/26/deep-nesting-with-has-many-through-and-a-join-model/
- [Rails nested form with has_many :through, how to edit attributes of join model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model)

Comment: Thank you. I followed your step. But i get a **no implicit conversion of Symbol to integer** error in the controller `def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:name, :specialization, :employees_specialization[:id, :specialization_id])
    end`

Comment: You have a syntax error. The colon (:) is on the wrong side of `employees_specialization`. And also, it's not `employees_specialization`, it's `employees_specializations_attributes`. Make it: `employees_specializations_attributes: [:id, :specialization_id]`

Comment: still no luck. not able to save it has an array. can save the same when i don't use the 'multiple' option in my select field in the form.