# Form for a has_many :through relation with additional attribute in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A `question` has_many `kpi` through `kpiquestions`:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kpiquestions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :kpis, through: :kpiquestions
end

class Kpi < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kpiquestions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :kpiquestions
end

class Kpiquestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kpi
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Now I have a working `question` form where I can add KPI's by using checkboxes:

```
= form_for @question do |f|
  = render "layouts/form_messages", target: @question
  .form-group
    = f.label "Name"
    = f.text_field :name
  .form-group
    = f.label "KPI's"
    %ul
      = hidden_field_tag "question[kpi_ids][]", nil
       - @kpis.each do |kpi|
        %li.checkbox
          = check_box_tag "question[kpi_ids][]", kpi.id, @question.kpi_ids.include?(kpi.id), "data-category" => kpi.id
          = kpi.name
  .form-group
      = f.submit(class: 'btn btn-default', value: "Save")
```

But the join table `kpiquestion` has an additional attribute `weight`. This attribute should also be added to the form, with a `text_field_tag`. Something like this:

```
= text_field_tag "question[kpi_ids][:weight]", kpi.weight, @question.kpi_ids.include?(kpi.id), "data-category" => kpi.weight
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because it now returns an error saying `kpi` has no attribute called `weight`. So how can I add this attribute to the form?

Comment: You should look into [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails nested form with has\_many :through, how to edit attributes of join model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to make the entire form_for into a form_tag that passes to a post request in the relevant controller, then the only thing limiting which parameters you can pass would be the the params you've chosen to allow controller-side. Obviously this is against convention, but it works great for cases like this.

Here is what the code would change to:

```
= form_tag question_index_path, :method => :post do
 = render "layouts/form_messages", target: @question *
 .form-group
   = label_tag "Name"
   = text_field_tag :name

 .form-group
   =label_tag :weight
   =text_field_tag :weight

 .form-group
   =label_tag "KPI's"
   = hidden_field_tag "question[kpi_ids][]", nil
   - @kpis.each do |kpi|
    %li.checkbox
      = check_box_tag "question[kpi_ids][]", kpi.id, @question.kpi_ids.include?(kpi.id), "data-category" => kpi.id
      = kpi.name

 .form-group
   =submit_tag("Save", class: btn btn-default)
```