# Rails app creating join records (has_many through) with a form fields_for section and collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm tearing my hair out with this. I have three models: `Game`, `Genre` and `GameGenre`. Games have many Genres through GameGenres, Genres have many Games through GameGenres.

I have a `games/new` form which creates new game records. To this form, I've added a `fields_for :game_genres` section, which is supposed to allow the user to add game_genre relationship records to the new game records they create.

I think I'm pretty close to getting this working. At the moment, on submission it returns the error: "Game genres game can't be blank." I take this to mean the form is connecting to the game_genres table. I'm not sure why the controller isn't submitting the :game_id value.

Here's my code.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@game) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title_en, "Game title (English)" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title_en, class: 'form-control',
                            placeholder: "E.g. Marble Madness" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :year, "Year" %>
    <%= f.select :year, options_for_select((1950..2017).reverse_each),
                                  {},
                                  {:class => 'form-control'} %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description_en, "Summary" %>
    <%= f.text_area :description_en, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <hr />

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.fields_for :game_genres do |gf| %>

      <%= gf.label :genre_id, "Select a genre" %>
      <%= gf.collection_select(:genre_id, Genre.all, :id, :name,
            {},
            {:class => "form-control"}) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary center-block" %>

<% end %>
```

**games_controller.rb** (excerpt)

```
def new
  @game = current_user.games.build
  @game.game_genres.build
end

def create
  @game = current_user.games.build(game_params)
  if @game.save
    flash[:success] = "Game saved: #{@game.title_en} (#{@game.year})"
    redirect_to game_path(@game.id)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

  def game_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:title_en, :year, :description_en,
                      game_genres_attributes: [:genre_id])
```

**game.rb**

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :game_genres,  foreign_key:  :game_id,
                          dependent: :destroy

  has_many :genres, through: :game_genres

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_genres,
                                allow_destroy: true
```

**genre.rb**

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :game_genres,  foreign_key:  :genre_id,
                          dependent: :destroy

  has_many :games, through: :game_genres
```

**game_genre.rb**

```
class GameGenre < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :game, inverse_of: :game_genres
  belongs_to :genre, inverse_of: :game_genres
```

As I understand it I do not need to add resources for game_genres to routes.rb.

This is the output from the rails development server when I try to submit a new game record:

```
Started POST "/games" for ::1 at 2015-06-30 18:59:24 +0100
Processing by GamesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cUbIu3i9niI0R8b9E3KZeYEbNpx8NDj9Jx1MeGvylYDKQj54d3BwSdLsMiPsRBoUTzoTEuMGTk5/KTKAXH7DMA==", "game"=>{"title_en"=>"fdsdcdc", "year"=>"2017", "description_en"=>"dsdc", "game_genres_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"genre_id"=>"8"}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "genres"."name" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "genres".* FROM "genres"  ORDER BY "genres"."name" ASC
```

As I understand it, the `game_genres_attributes` are properly nested and permitted. Why isn't game_id being recognised and saved?

Thanks so much to anyone who can help.

---

**EDIT:**

I got the form working by removing this validation from the GameGenre model:

```
validates :game_id, presence: true
```

I want this line in though, so I'm now wondering how to work around it?

---

EDIT 2:

I guess this is the answer (from http://makandracards.com/makandra/1346-popular-mistakes-when-using-nested-forms):

> Nested records are validating the presence of their nesting parent
>   record’s foreign key. If you do this, you cannot create a new parent
>   record together with a new child record and will need to save the
>   parent before you can save the child. You can opt to only show the
>   nested child form when the parent has been saved before, or simply let
>   go of the validation.

Comment: Try after adding this `game_genres_attributes: [ :id, :genre_id, :game_id]`..... and then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model)

Comment: @ArupRakshit - Thanks but I had tried that line to no avail. I will read your linked answer in a moment. I have just got the form working by removing the line `validates :game_id, presence: true` from the GameGenre model. Ideally I want that validation in, so how can I work around it?

Comment: Need to check the full code.. sometimes at least me not able to help by looking at the RoR post. Most the problem I solved by doing _debugging_ .. Rails app is a mixture of lots of things.. So need to debug to help.. Only these code wouldn't help me to help you.. :/

Comment: you need to pass the `game_id` while submitting the form.. see it is absent here `"game_genres_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"genre_id"=>"8"}`..

Comment: @ArupRakshit But the game_id doesn't exist until after the new game record is saved...

Comment: @ArupRakshit how do I pass it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82016/discussion-between-neil-wheatley-and-arup-rakshit).