# has_many :throught not INSTERING INTO database from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, has-many-through, strong-parameters

I have tried all of the solutions to similar problems and haven't gotten this one figured out.

I have a has_many :through relationship between 'Clinician', and 'Patient' with a joined model 'CareGroupAssignment'.  I would like to have a `patient` be able to have multiple `clinicians` associated with it and `clinicians` will have multiple `patients`.

When I submit my form this is logged:
`Started POST "/patients" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-02 14:56:38 -0700
Processing by PatientsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXX=", "patient"=>{"user_attributes"=>{"email"=>"allencentre", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "first_name"=>"Allen", "last_name"=>"Centre", "birth_date(1i)"=>"2002", "birth_date(2i)"=>"9", "birth_date(3i)"=>"2", "clinician_ids"=>["85", "87"], "patient_deceased"=>"0", "patient_archived"=>"0"}, "button"=>""}`

So `"clinician_ids"=>["85", "87"]` is being passed from the form.

There is an `INSERT INTO "users" ("email", ....` and an `INSERT INTO "patients" ("bir....` but the data for `care_group_assignments` doesn't have one.

There is `[36mCareGroupAssignment Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "care_group_assignments".* FROM "care_group_assignments"  WHERE "care_group_assignments"."patient_id" = $1[0m  [["patient_id", 199]]`

**clinician.rb** (simplified)

```
class Clinician < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :care_group

    has_many :patients ,:through=> :care_group_assignments
    has_many :care_group_assignments, :dependent => :destroy

    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user,  :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**patient.rb**

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :care_group

    has_many :clinicians ,:through=> :care_group_assignments
    has_many :care_group_assignments

    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user,  :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**care_group_assignments.rb**

```
class CareGroupAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :clinician
    belongs_to :patient
end
```

This is following the example from [Railscasts PRO #17- HABTM Checkboxes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2qwV0B9yfU) to at least start getting the data collected and to have the models set up correctly.  Below is the form with the checkboxes for each clinician as described in the RailsCast, checkboxes show up and the data is sent but not stored (can't figure out why).

patient **new.html.erb** form

```
<%= form_for @patient do |form| %>

  <%= form.fields_for :user do |builder| %>
   <div class="form-group">
      <%= builder.label "Email or Username" %>
      <%= builder.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= builder.label :password %>
      <%= builder.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :first_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First name" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :last_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last name" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <% Clinician.where(care_group_id: @care_group.id).each do |clinician| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "patient[clinician_ids][]", clinician.id, @patient.clinician_ids.include?(clinician.id), id: dom_id(clinician) %>
      <%= label_tag dom_id(clinician), clinician.full_name %><br>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <%= form.button 'Create Patient', class: "btn btn-u btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

This method has so far not been able to save the `clinician` to `patient` association.

**patient_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @patient = Patient.new
  @user = User.new
  @patient.build_user

  @care_group = current_clinician.care_group
end

def create
  @patient = Patient.create(patient_params)
  @patient.care_group = current_clinician.care_group

  if @patient.save
    redirect_to patient_path(@patient), notice: "New patient created!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

def show
 @patient = Patient.find_by(id: params["id"])
end

private
 def patient_params
  params.require(:patient).permit({:clinician_ids => [:id]},:first_name,:last_name,:user_id,:birth_date, user_attributes: [ :email, :password, :patient_id, :clinician_id ])
 end
```

I plan to display the `clinicians` associated with a `patient` on the patient `show` page:

patient **show.html.erb**

```
<strong>Shared with:</strong>
 <% @patient.clinicians.each do |clinician| %>
  <%= clinician.full_name %><
 <% end %>
```

This works if I seed the database but since the data doesn't seem to be stored, nothing is showing up.

Rails 4.1.8, ruby 2.2.1p85, PostgreSQL

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is this line in your controller:

```
params.require(:patient).permit({:clinician_ids => [:id]}...
```

It should be:

```
params.require(:patient).permit({:clinician_ids => []}...
```